# Is there any way to make glasses like Geo Stelar's Visualizer? Or is there a way to make glasses that can detect and see radio waves?

Tags: visible-light

Geo Stelar in the MegaMan Starforce series for Nintendo DS has these glasses called Visualizer's, they basically make it so he can see EM Wave's.  But I just want to know if there's a way to make glasses that allow people to "see" radio waves; or at least make transfer the radio wave to be visible light.

Comment: You have eyes that can see em waves just fine. One can, of course, make IR and deep IR cameras and they are readily available. Once we get to the microwave frequency range, things get a bit less interesting, as the resolution of a typical room would only be a few ten pixels. On the scale of geological features "seeing" with radar is extremely important. Synthetic aperture radar systems have been used on many spacecraft to "see" details of planets like Earth, Venus and moons  like Titan that are hidden underneath clouds or not visible in the optical. Is that what you mean by "seeing"?

Comment: Consider night vision goggles, or better yet, the IR, UV,x-ray and gamma-ray detectors on space and solar probes like Solar Dynamics Observatory, Fermi, GALEX, etc. They "see" all across the EM spectrum.  There is no "wave" motion to see (like you might view an ocean wave or a guitar string), however, but the intensity of the radiation is converted into false color on a viewing screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can construct imaging RF equipment. You'd see the images and not the signal wiggles (people looking at those used to be called worm watchers).

It's basically by having a small enough wavelength to resolve the different amplitudes received from different points in the target being imaged. You can have enough resolution to see those wavelengths from IR to gamma rays, and including visible light. For radio or microwaves frequencies you need larger, real or synthesized, apertures.

For radio waves you would need a huge (real or synthesized, see later) antenna to be able to get the resolutions to resolve objects maybe a few cms on a side. The half power beam width of dish antennas (and not too different for flat arrays) are about lambda/d, with d the linear size in that direction. So resolution is roughly Rxlambda/d. Depending on how far you are, you'll need a bigger or smaller antenna. For 3 GHz lambda = 3 cms., so if you want to get resolution on something about that size at say 100 m you need your antenna to be roughly of that linear dimensions. You can do a little better than that, maybe 50 m, and if you go up to 30 GHz you can do with about a 5 m antenna.

So that would pretty pretty large glasses or goggles, metallic with electronics. If you wanted that resolution in 2D you'd need it 5 m on a side or circular. That is called cross-range resolution, you are not exploiting the timing of the returned wave. If you wanted to also get the range resolution, i.e. 3D imaging, you need the radio wave to have the bandwidth (BW) for it, it's delta R = c/BW. For 1 GHz BW you get, about 30 cm. you can work things to be somewhat better, maybe a third or so to about 10 cms.

So, yes, you can see images, and not waves that way, but it's a pretty diffuse image you are seeing. If you want it sharper you need a larger effective antenna, and higher BW. The effective antenna is done is what is called a synthetic aperture (SAR) radar, you move or the target moves and you integrate coherently for maybe a second or so. That is what @CuriousOne was referring to in his question. It is a way to make an RF image. You get a much better cross range resolution image. For depth, or range resolution you need to increase BW, not easy, and in many cases the SAR images are just two dimensional. In astronomy the planetary motions are used to synthesize those baselines. SARs are used also in airborne and other imaging.

You can do something else, and it is having the antenna be distributed, i.e., have it be multiple antennas, but if widely separated there is an interferometer effect that has to be resolved - antennas separated more than lambda/2 will give you multiple ambiguous locations for the returns. You have to synthesize it. This is used in for instance in astronomy, the VLA, very large array interferometer. It uses spacing also in 2 dimensions to resolve the ambiguities. You could imagine a larger array of small glasses by different people, and though very smart and innovative collaborative signal processing synthesize it all. Good luck with that.

So, yes, you can see images and not waves at RF frequencies, but you have to work much harder.